# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

[!Here is the code where i got an error, I could not use [] for this code

```
return ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          itemCount: chatDocs?.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
              chatDocs[index].data()['text'],
              chatDocs[index].data()['username'],
              chatDocs[index].data()['userImage'],
              chatDocs[index].data()['userId'] == user.uid,


          ),
          // Container(
          //   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          //    child:  Text(chatDocs?[index]['text']),)
        );
```

I also tried null check and 'as Map' to chat-Docs, But both are didnot work

Comment: Please don't post pictures. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can edit your question and paste code instead of picture.

Answer (score 1):

add `.toList()` in chatDocs declaration line
so it becomes like this:

```
final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data?.docs.toList();
```

Comment: showing same error

Answer (score 0):

`.map` returns an `Iterable` which doesn't have the `[]` operator. You can solve this by turning it into a list by calling `toList()` on it. So

```
final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data?.docs.map(docs).toList();
```

But it looks like your `map()` is already wrong. Note the error there. Do you really need to map it? If not then this already should work

```
final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data?.docs;
```

Or actually this to handle it in case it's `null`

```
final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data?.docs ?? [];
```

Comment: Tried both solutions but got same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way,

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: _yoursteam,
          builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return MsgTile(
                           snapshot.data.docs[index]["msgId"],
                           snapshot.data.docs[index]["time"],
                          snapshot.data.docs[index]["message"],
                          snapshot.data.docs[index]["sender"],
                          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid ==
                              snapshot.data.docs[index]["uid"],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : Container();
          }),
        );
```